# Problem serving images from IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have 2 url's, seemingly they are identical except for case.

i.e

/admin/freetextbox/images/separator.vertical.gif   -   works

/Admin/freetextbox/images/separator.vertical.gif   -   fails with capital A for admin, instead redirects after a 302 Found to the log in page,  logging in simply redirects back to login.  IIS refuses to serve this file if using capital A for Admin.

/adMin/frEetextbox/images/separator.vertical.gif   -   All other mixes of case work

the folder is a Virtual Directory setup unter the root of the site in IIS and it's alias is 'Admin'

Comment: Hi, is this the URL as it appears in the browser (view source), or as it appears in your markup? ASP.net can do some funny things to paths of urls if it decides to be clever. Assuming this link is in an asp.net page, could you post the code that renders it?

Comment: it's an absolute url starting at http:// but i removed the site part.

Comment: O yea and the link is a gif served by iis.  I'm not sure it falls under asp.net but it is an asp.net site registered in iis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A further note, if I delete the file completely and copy it back in from source control IIS serves the files again. Must be permissions somewhere or possibly caching but I cannot find the source and one day this problem will rear its ugly head again but for now i have cheated.